# Repeat values a variable time on each row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to automatically populate a dynamic list where values are repeated on each row separately. The number of repetitions is in column `A` and the value to repeat is in column `B`. The formula should go into column `C`, like this:

[image: table expected behaviour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat values with the `sequence()` function like this:

`=sequence(1, A2, B2, 0)`

...where A2 contains the number of repetitions and B2 contains the value to repeat.

See [sequence()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244).

Comment: thanks
that's exactly the functionality

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)